# Incremental Source Generator generated code passed compilation with syntax error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I made a Incremental Source Generator:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It generates code that has an obvious syntax error

```
    [Generator]
    public class SourceGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator {
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context) {
            context.RegisterSourceOutput(context.AdditionalTextsProvider, static (context, name) => {
                string sourceCode = $@"
 public class {"AAA"}{{
    {{
 }}
 ";
                context.AddSource("AAA" + ".g.cs", sourceCode);
            });
        }
```

After building the solution for the first time and errors were expected. I restarted Visual Studio. I can see following code was generated:

```
 public class AAA{
    {
 }
```

When viewing this AAA.g.cs, the text editor didn't highlight the fault of less closing braket.
Then I build the solution for the second time. It was succeeded. How can this be possible?

Comment: The compiler creates intermediate obj files.  You may have multiple projects and when one project fails to compile the compiler stops and doesn't finish compiling all the projects.  So an obj file may contain errors when the compiler stops.  After fixing errors the compiler completes and obj files that didn't compile the first time gets compiled the second time.

Comment: @jdweng the first time error was simply because of the source generator was not built yet.

Comment: Did you get a syntax error in the code after you built it with the source generator?

Comment: Were you able to solve it @martinrhan?